# SIMPLE HTML DOM: Imprimir elemento hasta que encuentre un div

Tags: php, scraping

Buen dia a todos. Les paso a comentar lo que me sucede, estoy usando simple_html_dom.php para hacer scraping de una web mia, pero lo que quiero hacer es esto, que imprima el valor dentro de un `h2` por ejemplo, hasta que aparezca un `h1`, porque abajo de ese `h1` siguen apareciendo textos que hace scraping también, y no quiero, mi idea es que cuente hasta que aparezca esa etiqueta.

***Contador que suma todos los elementos que necesito:***

```
$contador = array();
foreach($htmlCont->find('a.name') as $element) { //lo que quiero que busque e imprima
  $contadores[0]=$contadores[0]+1;
}
```

Ahora, quiero que mientras cuente, si encuentra un `<h1 class="aaa">` se detenga, porque luego de este h1, siguen apareciendo `<a class="name">`

Espero poder explicarme, cualquier cosa me avisan e intento volver a explicar.
Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Agrego la estructura:

```
$htmlCont =  file_get_html('https://webscraping.net');
    $contador = array();
    foreach($htmlCont->find('h2.table-caption') as $element) {//elemento que si encuentra se detenga 
      $contadores[1]=$contadores[1]+1;
    }
    foreach($htmlCont->find('a.team-name') as $element) {//elemento que quiero que imprima hasta que encuentre un h2 de arriba
        $contadores[0]=$contadores[0]+1;
    }
```

Por ejemplo en mi web que hago el scraping:

```
<a class="team-name">equip</a> //Este si
<a class="team-name">equip</a> //Este si
<a class="team-name">equip</a> //Este si
<h2 class="table-caption">otro dia</h2>//aqui necesito que corte
<a class="team-name">equip</a> //Este no
<a class="team-name">equip</a> //Este no
<a class="team-name">equip</a> //Este no
```

Comment: ¿Podrías modificar tu pregunta para ayudarte con un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Es decir, que añadas un fragmento del HTML, cómo lees el fichero para obtener ese $htmlCont, etc. O sea, que podamos reproducir tu problema para dar con una posible solución

Comment: Que tal, gracias por responder, ahí edité la pregunta un poco, para ver si se logra entender.

Comment: Saludos. Sigo con este problema...

Comment: Disculpa, no me había perctado de la modifcación. En el HTML no aparece ningún `h1` para que se detenga, ¿no es lo que buscabas emular?